# .class:first-child not working

Tags: css

I want the following navigation menu to have a background colour of white.

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
<ul class="page-menu ancestor-tree">
    <li class="page_item page-item-5828 page_item_has_children current_page_item"><a href="http://www.example.com/investors/">Investors</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li class="page_item page-item-6150 page_item_has_children"><a href="http://www.example.com/investors/asx-announcements/">ASX Announcements</a>
            <ul class="children">
                <li class="page_item page-item-6348"><a href="http://www.example.com/investors/asx-announcements/asx-2017/">2017</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-6158"><a href="http://www.example.com/investors/shareholder-information/">Shareholder Information</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-6181"><a href="http://www.example.com/investors/presentations/">Presentations</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-6167"><a href="http://www.example.com/investors/research/">Research</a></li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-6171"><a href="http://www.example.com/investors/media/">Media</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- language: lang-css -->
.page-menu.ancestor-tree {background-color: white; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 1em; border-top: 2px solid #002f55; border-bottom: 1px solid #002f55;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree a {color: #4c4d4f; text-decoration: none;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li.current_page_item a {color: white;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li {padding: 15px 15px 8px 15px;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li ul li:hover {background-color: #1f486a;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li ul li:hover a {color: white;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li ul li.page_item_has_children:hover {background-image: url('../img/bg-li.png'); background-repeat: repeat-x; background-color: transparent;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li ul li:hover ul li a {color: #4c4d4f;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li ul li:hover ul li:hover a {color: white;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li ul {margin-left: 0; padding-top: 15px;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li ul li ul {padding-top: 0;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li.current_page_item {background-color: #003155;}
.page-menu ancestor-tree li.current_page_item:first-child {background-color: white; font-weight: bold;}
.page-menu.ancestor-tree ul li a:before {
    font-family: 'Zapf Dingbats';
    font-size: 15px;
    content: '\276F';
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

However, the menu as a whole has a background colour of `#003155`.

I've tried `.page-menu ancestor-tree li.current_page_item:first-child {background-color: white; font-weight: bold;}` but this selector is not being applied.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In :

```
.page-menu ancestor-tree li.current_page_item:first-child {background-color: white; font-weight: bold;}
```

Change :

```
.page-menu ancestor-tree
```

To :

```
.page-menu.ancestor-tree
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `.page-menu.ancestor-tree`

Answer (score 0):

The `li:first-child` selector means

> Select the first child of its parent if and only if it's an li
>   element.

There is `CSS3's` `:first-of-type` for your case:

```
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li:first-of-type{
   color: blue;
}
```

But with browser compatibility woes and whatnot, you're better off giving the first li a class, then targeting that class:

```
.page-menu.ancestor-tree li.first{
   color: blue;
}
```